# Return empty list instead of null

Tags: json, go, null, slice

I want to change my current function to return empty JSON list, currently it returns `nil`.

This is my current code:

```
func (s *Service) projectsGet(c *gin.Context) {
    var projects []*models.Project

    user := getUser(c)
    pag := models.NewPagination(c)

    ps, err := s.db.ProjectsGet(user.ID, &pag)
    if err != nil {
        apiError(c, http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }

    projects = ps
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, projects)
}
```

I want it to return `[]`, how I can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `nil` slice encodes to a `null` JSON object. This is documented at [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte encodes as a base64-encoded string, and **a nil slice encodes as the null JSON value**.

If you want a non-`null` empty JSON array, use a non-`nil` empty Go slice.

See this example:

```
type Project struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)

var ps []*Project
enc.Encode(ps)

ps = []*Project{}
enc.Encode(ps)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4j26-eNEujb)):

```
null
[]
```

So in your case make sure `projects` is not `nil`, for example:

```
projects = ps
if projects == nil {
    projects = []*models.Project{}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to handle this is to check if the slice is nil and initialize it:

```
projects = ps
if projects == nil {
    projects = make([]*models.Project, 0)
}
```

This can be tedious if you have several structs and structs with arrays. To handle those, you can create custom marshalers or dynamically inspect fields.

Source: [Arrays and JSON in Go](https://medium.com/@stnguyen90/arrays-and-json-in-go-98540f2fa74e)